# Topics of object perception for pr2

Tags: ros, gazebo

I started to use ROS hydro (Robot Operating System) on ubuntu, using the simulator "Gazebo" and roscpp library, in order to program some robots.

In case of pick up and place known objects by robots, what are the topics of object perception for pr2 in ROS??

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* J.butterfly, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what what you would like to achieve, what you have tried, what you expected to see & what you actually saw. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to help you edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Also, I know that it's easy to accidentally create multiple accounts when first starting on Stack Exchange, so you might find [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) useful.